# Display video in laravel-8

Tags: laravel-8

[image: see image here]
you can see i can store video in my public/video folder
Now I want to show it on my news/show.blade.php but its not working
This is my show.blade.php

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="/video/{{ $news->video }}" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="/video/{{ $news->video }}" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

This is my NewsController.php

```
public function show(News $news)
{
  return view('news.show',compact('news'));
}
```

After all that I can just do it but video is not loading and playing see image
[image: See image]

Comment: What does `{{ $news->video }}` contain? Did you check the source to make sure the video file name is inserted? Depending on your browser you might need to allow it to show/play media

Comment: $news is the variable which come form show function. And video is name of my table column where I store my vedio

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors/warning messages?

Comment: no therer is no error

Comment: no therer is no error